# Como manejar Ajax dentro de un mismo archivo php para pasar variables de javascript a php

Tags: javascript, php

para los que ya me conocen estoy en un proyecto para hacer un calendario pero todavia tengo problemas con el php. Precisamente con el ajax, pues en mi archivo php, tengo el html, y el javascript, y quiero dentro de una funcion en javascript pasar una variable a php.

Como dije, mi archivo es un .php donde tengo funciones en javascript

```
<script>

function openDayMenu(selected_day){

//Aqui imprimo la fecha como titulo

month.textContent = monthNames[monthNumber];
days.textContent = dayNumber[selected_day];
year.textContent = currentYear.toString();

//Aqui abajo, EN RESUMEN, genero una tabla con cada hora del día (de 1 a 24)
//y de cada consulta a la base de datos, imprimo los eventos que tiene cada hora

dates.innerHTML = `
    <div id="scroll">
    <table >
        <tr>                                    
             <th>Hora</th> 
             <th>Evento</th>  
        </tr>

        <?php
            $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','agenda');                     
            

            for($i = 1; $i<=24; $i++){

                    echo '<tr>
                            <td>';
                    echo  $i;
                    echo '</td>
                    <td class="subline">';

                    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM citas WHERE fecha LIKE '2021-07-22' AND hora_inicio LIKE '0$i%'";       
                    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

                    while($mostrar=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

                        echo '
                            <div style="margin-bottom: 3px">
                            <input type="button" name="boton" value="';
                        echo $mostrar['titulo']; 
                        echo '"class="eventosPorHora">
                              Inicia: ';
                        echo $mostrar["hora_inicio"];
                        echo  '
                              </div>
                              '; 
                        
                    }

                    echo '</td>
                    </tr>';
            }
        ?>

    </table>
    </div>
    `;

}
</script>
```

Lo que quiero hacer, es que en mi consulta "SELECT * FROM citas WHERE fecha LIKE '2021-07-22' AND hora_inicio LIKE '0$i%'":

La fecha tambien tiene que ser automatica, y deberia ser correspondiente al día seleccionado (el parámetro de la función) tal que asi: WHERE fecha LIKE '2021-07-$selected_day'
y quiero saber como pasarle esa variable del javascript al php.

Hice esto en ajax, pero quiero saber como puedo solucionarlo:

```
<?php        //al inicio del documento inicio una sesion

    session_start();

?>

<script>

function openDayMenu(selected_day){

month.textContent = monthNames[monthNumber];
days.textContent = dayNumber[selected_day];
year.textContent = currentYear.toString();

$.ajax({
         type:"POST",
         url: "recibir.php",
         data: {JS_day: selected_day+1},
         success:function(result){
             console.log(result);
         }
})

dates.innerHTML = `
    <div id="scroll">
    <table >
        <tr>                                    
             <th>Hora</th> 
             <th>Evento</th>  
        </tr>

        <?php             

            $conexion=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','agenda');   
            $selected_day = $_SESSION[selected_day];

            for($i = 1; $i<=24; $i++){

                    echo '<tr>
                            <td>';
                    echo  $i;
                    echo '</td>
                    <td class="subline">';

                    $consulta = "SELECT * FROM citas WHERE fecha LIKE '2021-07-$selected_day' AND hora_inicio LIKE '0$i%'";       
                    $result = mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta);

                    ...
                    ...(lo demas)
}
```

En el archivo recibir.php hice esto:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    
    $selected_day = $_POST['JS_day'];
    $_SESSION["selected_day"] = $selected_day;

?>
```

El problema es que no me logra reconocer la variable $selected_day, y no se que pudo estar mal, sí la variable la estoy mandando al archivo, y estoy recibiendola por la sesion mas abajo en el php.

Comment: ¿Qué variable no logra reconocer? Por otra parte, el archivo .php que recibe los datos desde Ajax y devuelve una respuesta, debe ser diferente del archivo que contiene dicha petición, lo digo porque veo esto: `url: "#",` y no, Ajax no funciona así, debes tener un archivo independiente que sea el encargado de recibir/procesar los datos.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar. La variable es precisamente la que envio por ajax, y estoy queriendo recibir del php. Precisamente ya averigué y efectivamente necesitaría mandarlo a otro archivo para recibir los datos, pero aun haciendo eso, como puedo retornar la variable precisamente de vuelta al archivo a ese momento para la consulta que estoy haciendo abajo con php?

Comment: La respuesta se recibe aquí: `success:function(result){console.log(result);}` Revisa la consola y verifica si se imprime algo. Si no funciona completa la pregunta. Te recomiendo también que leas un poco sobre cómo funciona Ajax, aquí hay algunas preguntas donde se explica, y en la red hay varios tutoriales...

Comment: Y, en el parámetro `url` de la petición Ajax tienes que poner la carpeta/archivo php que recibirá/procesará la petición Ajax. Por favor, revisa documentación y/o tutoriales o preguntas/respuestas de aquí, arma tu código y si tienes algún problema pregunta con todos esos puntos ya esclarecidos. Tu código no puede funcionar como lo tienes ahora, te faltan pasos previos de comprensión que debes abordar con paciencia. Ajax es muy simple una vez entiendas esos aspectos fundamentales.

Answer (score 0):

Para mi no necesitas usar ajax en este caso, ajax sirve para comunicarte con php, o con cualquier backend.

Otra opción mejor...

```
window.location.href= window.location +' ?dato=' + variable_mia;
```

desde php:

```
if(isset($_GET['dato'])){$dato=$_GET['dato']; echo $dato;}
```

............................................................................

Algo mucho más simple todavia, si al final vas a hacerlo con un archivo externo PHP...

```
const send_data = async()=>{
const consulta= await fetch('server.php?dato=' + variable_mia);
const res = await consulta.text();
return res;
}
// y después llamas a console.log(send_data());
```

Comment: Hola bro, precisamente es al reves, lo que quiero es pasar de js a php. Y si, si ves lo que edite, ya logré pasar con ajax, pero a otro archivo ! y lo que quiero es, en mi mismo archivo donde tengo el js, obtener la variable en mi función de js donde más abajo tengo php y hago una consulta. Ahí es donde quiero usar la variable de js, pero lo unico que me hace ajax es mandarla a otro archivo php.